# PC Controllable DC Power supply (0-30V)

Tags: valves, electrical, circuit-design, electronics

I have a Proportional solenoid valve that uses a 0-30VDC for control (opening the orifice) I only have capability to provide 0-5V or 0-10V. I need to control the valve using my PC. Is there any DC Power supply device that I can control using PC to provide 0-30V (that I can change continuously as required during operation)? I have tried a voltage multiplier circuit. I am getting the required voltage but the Transistors (BC547) are burning out quickly due to over-current/heating.

I am not a electrical/electronics engineer hence don't know if there is a better transistor or how to choose one.

Hence, searching for the PC controllable DC Power supply. if available.
[image: This is the circuit I have tested. But the BC547 transistor is burning out after 5 min.]

Comment: There are plenty of controllable power supplies. What is your budget?

Comment: Can you post the diagram of the voltage multiplier circuit? Also take look at [E3630 Series Bench Power Supply](https://www.keysight.com/us/en/products/dc-power-supplies/bench-power-supplies/e3630-series-bench-power-supply-80-200w.html) They are expensive but will do the job.

Comment: I have added the Image of the circuit to my Question. I have 6 proportional solenoid valves to control and each requires  0-30VDC to operate. 0V for close and 30 V for 100% open. Any voltage in between opens the valve by a proportional amount

Comment: I have a NI DAQ that can provide 0-10VDC or 0-5VDC to control the voltage multiplier or the DC power supply

Comment: @ZenMaster Have you considered a NI - DAQ module such as [NI-9512
C Series Motor Drive Interface Module](http://www.ni.com/en-us/support/model.ni-9512.html)

Comment: You are attempting to use a switching transistor to drive a power load.  Absolute maximum I_c is 100mA.  And you want 400mA.  No wonder it burns out.

Comment: You also need a base resistor to limit current.

Comment: Well, I finally got a working circuit(somewhat). Instead of BC547, I am now using a CL100B NPN transistor which has masimum current capacity if 1A. The cicruit has not failed yet. The only issue now is the offset voltage at output (around 0.125 V when input is 0V)  Also, I definitetely need to use a heat sink and ensure proper airflow since the Temp does  shoot up to beyond 150 Degree Celius when run for an extended period of time. \n( In case it helps anyone in the future also came across a DC Power Supply that was afforable - Scientific PSD7303A (333$).This one is same as Siglent SPD3303X-E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a good device that served my purpose very well.

https://www.scientificindia.com/products/programmable-3-channel-power-supply-1.aspx

[image]

This type of device is also available from manufacturers like Siglent outside India.

Thank you for all the responses.

Answer (score 0):

One good solutions is to use a [L298N Dual H-Bridge breakout board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9670). There are plenty of of  these boards in the market. The Break out board looks something like the following

[image: Motor Driver 2A Dual L298 H-Bridge]

Based on the image below it should be able to handle your voltage requirements.

[image]

Also the BC547 transistor has max current of 100mA. The Solenoid most likely is sourcing more than 100mA of currents.

### [image]

**References:**

- [How to Use L298N Motor Driver](https://www.teachmemicro.com/use-l298n-motor-driver/)
- [Motor Driver 2A Dual L298 H-Bridge](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9670)
- [BC546/547/548/549/550](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/BC546.pdf)

Comment: @MahendraGunawardane Thank you very much for the suggestions. I will definitely see if the L298N Dual H-Bridge breakout board  works wit the valves.       At this point ordering NI modules and waiting for it will consume a lot of time. Also, I will need at least three such modules to individually control the valves making the whole affair very expensive. We decided to make our own control circuit because the valve providers(Cole - Parmer) was charging exorbitant amounts(around 520$ each ) for the controller alone.